# Saving a Linq Query and Using When Resuming from Tombstoning

Tags: silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-objects

I have a `List` of 500 objects that are queried against. When tombstoning, rather than save those 500 object to `State`, I'm wanting to save the query itself so that upon returning, I can just plug that into my class that shows the query of the 500 objects.

So if I have `Dim pictures = (From s In p.AllPictures Where s.IsFavorite = True Order By s.Index Ascending).ToList`, how can I save just the query itself to `State` so that upon returning from tombstoning I can assign that query to `pictures`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't save a query per say, as the query is code and not data. You probably mean to assign the result of the query?

Simply save your `pictures` variable to the `State` rather than the `p.AllPictures`.

Comment: Be aware though that the data needs to be serializable and that re-activating your app can take a significant time when the dataset is large and needs to be deserialized.

Comment: I'm trying to get away from `State` - it causes an enormous amount of time to reload my app (like 10-15 seconds), even from dormant state (i.e. not only tombstoned state). @invalidusername is spot on.

Comment: You should IList within an Virtualization control (such as ListBox or StackPanel) so only the items are loaded/displayed that the user is currently seeing. Then you could consider only storing the currently visible items and then reload the rest of the data in a BackgroundWorker when the users returns in your app. This sound somewhat complicated, which makes me believe that probably other people already had this problem and fixed it. Sorry i can't help you more.